# Arrow is not plotted

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Why is the first arrow not plotted? There is no error after running the script. There should be three arrows but there are only two arrows. Thank you

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import math
import matplotlib.patches as patches        

# Plot figure with size
fig, ax = plt.subplots(sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(5,5))

# Axis - lim
plt.xlim(-1.5, 1.5)
plt.ylim(-1.5, 1.5)

shift = 0.011
length = 1.3
coord_45 = math.sqrt(1/2)

# Plot an arrow
style="Simple,tail_width=0.5,head_width=4,head_length=8"
kw = dict(arrowstyle=style)
a3 = patches.FancyArrowPatch((0, 0.366618), (0.211427, 0.211427),connectionstyle="arc3,rad=10", **kw)
ax.scatter(0, 0, marker = 'o', s=30)

arrow = mpatches.FancyArrowPatch((0, 0-shift), (0, length), arrowstyle=style)
plt.gca().add_patch(arrow) 

arrow = mpatches.FancyArrowPatch((0, 0), (coord_45, -coord_45), arrowstyle=style)
plt.gca().add_patch(arrow) 

plt.savefig('file.pdf') 
plt.show()
```

Comment: `plt.gca().add_patch(a3)`?

Comment: Thank you very much